# Get matrix product of 3 matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, rotational-matrices

I have 3, 3X3 matrices stored in numpy arrays.
I want to get the product, to compute a rotation matrix.

Currently what I am doing is 
`rotation_matrix = (a * b * c)` but I don't know if this is the correct way to multiply matrices - should I be using `.dot` I have also tried with `rotation_matrix = pre_rotation.dot(result_pre_tilt).dot(post_rotation)`

and `rotation_matrix = np.multiply(result_pre_tilt, pre_rotation, post_rotation)`

```
a = np.array(
[[-0.25091924  0.         -0.        ]
[-0.         -0.35485339  0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.70710678]])

b = np.array(
[[ 0.10040533 -0.          0.        ]
[ 0.          0.28953198 -0.        ]
[ 0.          0.          0.31056766]])

c = np.array(
[[  6.12323400e-17   0.00000000e+00  -1.00000000e+00]
[  0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
[  1.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   6.12323400e-17]])
```

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html

Comment: Is this giving the right result?  An example might help.  `3D matrices` might be ambiguous.  Is the shape 3x3 or 2x3x4?  Or something else.

Comment: *"3D matrices stored in numpy arrays"*  What *type* are they, `matrix` or `ndarray`?  (Check `type(a)`.)  If they are `matrix` objects, then yes, `*` is matrix multiplication.  If they are `numpy.ndarray` objects, then `*` is elementwise multiplication.  To do matrix multiplication in that case, use the `dot` method: `rotation_matrix = a.dot(b).dot(c)`.  (You can use `dot` with `matrix` objects, too.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Those are regular numpy arrays, not `matrix` objects.  Use the `dot` method (or, if you are using shiny new Python and numpy versions, use `@`: `rotation_matrix = a @ b @ c`).

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `dot` like this:

```
final= numpy.dot(tilt_matrix, (numpy.dot(rotation_matrix, original))
```

Things to consider:

1. `numpy.dot` is a function, not a method (not possible to call `A.dot(B)`, call `np.dot(A, B)` instead);
2. The order matters - if you are not getting the right result, try changing the order. Sometimes you need to translate first and then rotate, sometimes the opposite. Depends on each case;
3. The left matrix column number must be the same size of the right matrix row number, for 2D matrices.

Comment: If `A` is a numpy array, `A.dot(B)` is the same as `np.dot(A,B)`.